# Add service principal using Graph client Sdk using proof jwt

Tags: azure-active-directory

I need to add a key credential to Azure active directory app using one of the existing key credentials. The Api action for it is explained here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/functions-and-actions#addkey-add-a-keycredential-for-an-application--

I use an existing key credential to sign the jwt proof as explained and it works fine.

I need a similar functionality in the Active directory Graph client sdk. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient/

The ActiveDirectoryClient.ServicePrincipals.AddServicePrincipalAsync method does not take a proof input. And currently if I call only taking an auth token it says "not enough privelge".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nuget package that you have included has a last update of 10-17-2016.

Per the samples included in that Nuget package :

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-web

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-console

Both have been archived. This library linked is neither maintained nor supported anymore. My suggestion would be to move over to utilize ADAL so that you can make http calls to the AAD Graph API.

> The more preferred option is the Microsoft Graph as Microsoft is
>   moving towards having all apis under the Microsoft Graph. And
>   Preferably moving to MSAL as that is the library that will be used
>   moving forward as well.
>
> However the issue with that is the addkey is not supported yet under
>   the Microsoft Graph. See here for differences in the Microsoft graph
>   and the AAD Graph currently. The idea is that there will be parity
>   between the two over time.

For an example on using the ADAL library making a call to the Microsoft Graph please see the following sample : https://github.com/FrankHu-MSFT/ADAL-.NET-Console-Application
Note that your setup will be similar but the only difference is that you'll be getting an access token on behalf of the AAD Graph API and making calls to the AAD Graph API accordingly.

For more up to date MSAL samples making calls to the Microsoft Graph API, please take a look at the samples here : https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-snippets-sample

As ADAL and the AAD Graph API are both getting older, it is suggested to move towards the Microsoft Graph API and MSAL when possible.